# Issue with async.waterfall in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, async.js

Scenario: 
I have a bunch of firebase data that I need to change sequentially and if something fails, I need to stop further processing.

Strategy:
Using async.waterfall. This way I can pass on variables as necessary to the next iteration and signal failures as well.

Issue:
When I have three or more data items to modify, I get stuck after the second item, trying to do a callback.

Code:

```
var processData =  function(<params>) {
  var funcArray = [];
  funcArray.push(processItemInitial);
  for(var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    funcArray.push(processItem);
  }

  async.waterfall(funcArray, function (err, status) {
    console.log("status: " + status);
    console.log("err: " + err);
  });
}

//uses global variable
var processItemInitial = function (callback) {
  productsRef.child(<some var>).child('quantity').transaction(function(data){
    if(data != null) {
      //do stuffs
    } else {
      console.log("null data");
    }
    return data;
  }).then(function() {
    callback(<params>);
  });
}

// uses variables passed through call backs
var processItem = function (<params>) {
  productsRef.child(<some var>).child('quantity').transaction(function(data){
    if(data != null) {
    //do stuffs
    } else {
      console.log("null data");
    }
    return data;
  }).then(function() {
    callback(<params>);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading the issue as you want to stop execution if something goes wrong. Async provides a really nice way to do this. From docs:

> However, if any of the tasks pass an error to their own callback, the next function is not executed, and the main callback is immediately called with the error
>   http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall

You should be able to call `callback` with an error as the first arg if something goes wrong. You have cases set up for `if ( data != null )` so use the `else` case of that to send `callback( 'No data found for <some var>' )`

```
var processItem = function (<params>) {
  productsRef.child(<some var>).child('quantity').transaction(function(data){
    if(data != null) {
    //do stuffs
    } else {
      callback( 'Data not found for <some var>' );
      console.log("null data");
    }
    return data;
  }).then(function() {
    callback(<params>);
  });
}
```

If a lack of data isn't the error you're worried about and you're worried about Firebase issues, you can `.catch()` errors since you're using "Thenable" references: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Thenable#catch

```
var processItem = function (<params>) {
  productsRef.child(<some var>).child('quantity').transaction(function(data){
    if(data != null) {
    //do stuffs
    } else {
      console.log("null data");
    }
    return data;
  }).then(function() {
    callback(<params>);
  }).catch( function( error ) {
    // Will exit the waterfall
    callback( error );
  });
}
```

Comment: This helped me debug an issue in my code. I was getting an exception that I wasn't seeing since I wasnt catching it.